# migrate import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar; jdk11 to jakarta in jdk17

Tags: java, java-17, ws

I have an application that I must migrate from jdk11 to jdk17 and when trying to generate my soap classes they are generated with the following import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar; in jdk17 javax it becomes jakarta but I can't find the XMLGregorianCalendar counterpart, could someone guide me in which library applies in this case.
I need change this:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
```

to this, but the last import i don't know how do it this:

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
    import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
    import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
```

Comment: Why do you want to migrate `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;`? It is part of the JRE since Java 5 and has not been removed. It is e.g. available in Java 11.

Comment: Thanks Robert, yes I'll keep using that class

Answer (score 3):

The `XMLGregorianCalendar` is in the "javax.xml" package as it still is part of the "main" java project so you can use it as is.

You can read its documentation of the last version (20 as of writing the answer) at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html